# Is anyone aware about below error in antlr4 parsing?

Tags: java, antlr4, grammar

Error Message:

```
line 8:95 missing 'check' at 'check'
```

```
trigger:
    TRIGGER_ (trigger_type)
;

trigger_type:
    TRIGGER_TYPE_CHECK

;
```

I am not able to figure out the error in my parser.g4, I have provided correct input string but still it shows above below message.

Comment: Can you also add the lexer rules for TRIGGER_ and TRIGGER_TYPE_CHECK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are most probably 2 (or more) lexer rules that match the input `"check"`. Assuming `TRIGGER_TYPE_CHECK` matches `"check"`, then something like this likely happens:

```
ID : [a-zA-Z]+;
TRIGGER_TYPE_CHECK : 'check';
```

In the case above, `"check"` will always become an `ID` and never a `TRIGGER_TYPE_CHECK`. You need to place `TRIGGER_TYPE_CHECK` above `ID`:

```
TRIGGER_TYPE_CHECK : 'check';
ID : [a-zA-Z]+;
```

Note that all other keywords need to be placed above `ID`. Of course, `"check"` will now never become an `ID`. If you want `"check"` to be both an `ID` and a `TRIGGER_TYPE_CHECK`, you need to do something like this:

```
id : ID | TRIGGER_TYPE_CHECK;

TRIGGER_TYPE_CHECK : 'check';
ID : [a-zA-Z]+;
```

and then use `id` instead of `ID` in your parser rules.

Comment: Here, what does this ID refers to?

Comment: That refers to a lexer rule in your grammar that also matches the input `"check"`. You could edit your question and add your complete grammar so that I can give an answer more tailored to your grammar.

Comment: Thanks, It got resolved actual issue was two keys were there in Lexer rules having same value as 'check'.